# WordPress - $instance variable is empty on widget() function

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I was trying to code a wordpress widget but my `$instance` variable in widget function is empty but i don't know why.

```
class mi_widget extends WP_Widget {    
    public function __construct () {
       // instrucciones para esta función
        parent::__construct(
            'mi_widget', // $id_base
            'Soy un widget formidable', // $name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Widget formidable que hace maravillas', 'mi-widget' ), ) // $widget_options
        );
    }
    public function widget ($args, $instance) {
        // instrucciones para esta función
        extract($args);
        echo $before_widget.$before_title;
        echo print_r($instance['mi_campo']);
        echo $after_title.$after_widget;
    }
    public function update ($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        // instrucciones para esta función
        $instance = array();
        $instance['mi_campo'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['mi_campo'] );
        return $instance;
    }
    public function form($instance) {
        // instrucciones para esta función
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'mi_campo' ] ) ) {
            $mi_campo = $instance[ 'mi_campo' ];
        }
        else {
            $mi_campo = __( 'Valor por defecto', 'mi-widget' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'mi_campo' );  ?>"><?php _e('T&iacute;tulo:', 'mi-widget'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'mi_campo' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name ( 'mi_campo' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr ($mi_campo); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }
    function get_field_name($field_name) {
        return 'widget-' . $this->id_base . '[' . $this->number . '][' . $field_name . ']';
    }
    function get_field_id($field_name) {
        return 'widget-' . $this->id_base . '-' . $this->number . '-' . $field_name;
    }

} // Cierra la clase
```

I am using the widget outside of my sidebar, I am using it in `front-page.php` with this code:

```
<?php the_widget( 'mi_widget' ); ?>
```

and i am registering the widget like this in my `functions.php` file:

```
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget('mi_widget');
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'=>'Home Widgets',
            'id'=>'sidebar-1',
            'class'=>'custome',
            'description'=>'Here you can set the widgets that you want to display in home page.'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );
```

Answer (score 1):

$instance will be filled if you place the widget into a sidebar and fill its form. If you're calling the widget directly using `the_widget` function then you should pass the $instance as second parameter. For example the following code:

`the_widget('mi_widget', array('mi_campo'=>'blahblah'))`

Please refer to this link for page information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget

I hope it helps.